# Grails: cant create tables on mysql

Tags: mysql, grails

I can run my grails app against the built in memory DB, but when I try to get it to work with MYSQL, it always fails to create the schema with the below error.

```
2014-04-11 16:05:16,445 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - Unsuccessful: create table registration_code (id bigint not null auto_increment, date_created datetime not null, token varchar(255) not null, username varchar(255) not null, primary key (id)) type=InnoDB 
2014-04-11 16:05:16,448 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'type=InnoDB' at line 1 
2014-04-11 16:05:16,449 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - Unsuccessful: create table report (id bigint not null auto_increment, version bigint not null, category varchar(255) not null, description longtext not null, name varchar(255) not null unique, reportsql longtext not null, views integer not null, primary key (id)) type=InnoDB
```

This error tells me almost nothing.

It could be that its trying to create a mysql schema against he built in memory DB for some reason.

the registration_code table is presumably part of spring security module I have installed.
the "report" table I can create by hand, it contains no reserved words or similar.

In mysql, I created a database with the same name as the application (I am guessing I have to do this). The user I'm using has global permissions on everything, and the created db.

Is there any way to debug this?  e.g. any way to see what SQL grails is trying to use?

I have tried to call all my domain objects and fields things which are not reserved (e.g. secRoles instead of roles)

My datasource.groovy looks like this:

```
dataSource {
    dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect
    pooled = true
    jmxExport = true
    driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    properties {
        maxActive = -1
        minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=1800000
        timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=1800000
        numTestsPerEvictionRun=3
        testOnBorrow=true
        testWhileIdle=true
        testOnReturn=true
        validationQuery="SELECT 1"
      }
}
environments {
    development {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "create"
            username = "myuser"
            password = "mypass"
            url = 'jdbc:mysql://localhost/'
        }
```

mysql 5.6
grails 2.3.6
Windows server.

Comment: Seems to have something to do with this: "MySQL 5.5 doesn't support "type" table option, instead it uses ENGINE option."  It seems that grails 2.3.6 out of the box does not support MSSQL server 5.6.  What?

Comment: Why should Grails support MySQL out of the box rather than Oracle, Postgres, etc. Even if this were a good idea (and I don't think it is), how would Grails know which machine MySQL is running on or which username and password to log in with? An in-memory database is the only sensible default

Comment: I did not mean that grails should by default not use the in memory db. I meant it shoudld have a commented out example or similar showing how to connect to mysql. I had to find an example on the internet, which of course turned out to be old and non working.

Answer (score 2):

OK, the solutions is this:

```
dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```

rather than:

```
dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect
```

Shame that grails does not come with an example mysql connection in the default conf file.

Comment: same is true still in 2017 for MyIsam: use org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5MyISAMDialect